# Android Finger Print local authentication within app

Tags: android

i need to authenticate user with finger print using finger print dialogue within  app to verify user.[I have tried this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial)  but it show this error

> register at least one finger print

Although 3 finger prints already registered in device (Samsung s5 os marsmallow)

Comment: Paste your code to see what 's going on. I have the same device and I can test it

Comment: code is same as in the given link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

FingerprintManager class Required the Android device should have built in os 6.0 otherwise isHardwareDetected() and hasEnrolledFingerprints() return false
S5 Android OS, v4.4.2 (KitKat), upgradable to v6.0 (Marshmallow)

```
final FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = getSystemService(FingerprintManager.class);
        if(fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
            if (fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device has FingerPrint", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            fingerprintManager.authenticate(new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(criper),mCancellationSignal , 0, new FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, CharSequence errString) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FingerPrint Not Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialogue.dismiss();
                    mCancellationSignal.cancel();

                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loginRequest(false);
                    mManage.setStringValue("name",emailtxt.getText().toString());
                    mManage.setStringValue("pass",passwordtxt.getText().toString());
                    mManage.setBooleanValue("TouchID",true);
                    dialogue.dismiss();
                }
            }, null);
        }
```